# How to remove postfix from autonumbering in crm 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

How can I remove or hide the suffix from quotes autonumbering?

It's enough to suffix does't appear in quotes template.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Quote Autonumbering is a standard feature of Dynamics CRM and can't be changed to remove a part.

You can always create another field to use as Quote Number and use an alternative Autonumber solution (like this [one](http://celedonpartners.com/blog/celedon-autonumber-solution-for-dynamics-crm/))

If I remember correctly the quotenumber field of the quote entity can be set to a custom value when the record is created so you can try first to set the autonumber solution to fill the quotenumber field, if doesn't work you need to create a new field.

Answer (score 2):

I create a new field and set field type to calculated with

condition  -> If Quote ID contains data

and action -> TrimRight(quotenumber, 5)

and then use it in quote Template .

It's Done .

Thanks Guido for your clue .